# Gradient boosting for multitask learning

Tags: boosting, social-network, optimization

Let's say I have relation learning task similar to what is solved here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6652

Simply put, I have a social graph with some nodes marked up with some tags, and I have to infer tags for unlabeled nodes. I have various sources of information for that : e.g. text, graph topology, etc and for each source I derived respective loss function. 
So, in order to train my model ( which resembles multitask learning at its heart ) I have to minimize complex loss function like this:

$$
 L_{T}\left ( R_{i}, v_{i}, m_{i} \right ) = \sum L_{text}\left ( v_{i} \right ) + \lambda_{1} L_{topology}\left ( v_{i} \right ) + 
\lambda_{2}L_{preferences}\left ( v_{i} \right )+...
$$

You see that many losses are actually here, and I have to determine these lambdas as well.
I suppose, that the best way to learn these lambdas could be to use boosting, and gradient boosting in particular ( as it's known for its scalability and ability to build strong classifiers from weaker ones )

But I'm  concerned about the power of my weak hypothesis space ( it consists of just two or three functions ). Could it be an obstacle for determining valuable lambdas? Or I need something more smart, than boosting, in my case.

Note that I'm trying to optimize tunable parameters of my model using respective loss functions and the combination of these functions simultaneously. This process ( hopefully ) will emit consistently improving classification results as model goes on and on ( starting from completely random state ), because free parameters will be updated according to this complex loss function.

Thanks in advance for pointing me at relevant papers, in which multiple loss functions are jointly optimized!

Comment: This paper may be useful *Do we Need Hundreds of Classifiers to Solve Real World Classification Problems?* ungated pdf here ... http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/delgado14a/delgado14a.pdf

Comment: Thank you, @DJohnson, but my point here is that in essence I'm learning very complex low-dimensional embedding using multiple functions ( and use obtained embedding as feature vector for classification ). So, RF is not an option for me ( because it's impossible to build and embedding using it ). But thank you anyway! :-)

Comment: Ok...your comment reminded me of Hyndman's *functional data analysis* and the wide range of methods developed in that class of models.

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to find relevant info in Hyndman's publications. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: It was just a suggestion. If you've browsed his pubs and nothing seemed relevant, then forget about it.